# Problems with a search query in PHP

Tags: php

I have a search query in PHP where you can search in the user database. It's important that only users connected to one specific ID (w_id) shows. And every user have one. In other words, I do not want others administrators to see clients who do not belong to the searcher.

So I have specified a w_id for every user. 
My problem is that it looks like my query is ignoring that.

Here's my code.

```
   $raw_search_results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers
   WHERE (`firstname` LIKE '%".$search."%') 
   OR (`lastname` LIKE '%".$search."%')
   OR (`adress` LIKE '%".$search."%')
   OR (`email` LIKE '%".$search."%') AND w_id='$webshop_info[w_id]' limit 0,50")
   or die(mysqli_error());
```

This code shows all the users with `w_id` 4, 3, 6 etc, but it should be only users with 1 because `$webshop_info[w_id]` is defined as 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try escaping the query to insert the $webshop_info

Comment: Maybe brackets could help `WHERE ((...) OR (...) ...) AND ...`

Comment: Indeed, and has priority over or.

Comment: what is `w_id` type? integer or string? what will happen if you use `$webshop_info[w_id]` value directly? e.g. `w_id='1'`

Comment: @revo I've tried, same results. Weird.

Comment: please reply to my 1st question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group all of your 'OR' statements using parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (... OR ... OR ...) AND ...
```

You can read more about operator precedence [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: That makes absolutely sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE ((`firstname` LIKE '%".$search."%')
  OR (`lastname` LIKE '%".$search."%')
  OR (`adress` LIKE '%".$search."%')
  OR (`email` LIKE '%".$search."%'))
  AND (w_id='$webshop_info[w_id]') LIMIT 0, 50
```

Note the the `where ( (condition1) or (condition2)) & (condition)`

Please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, use prepared query with stakeholders.

For example: (please do not copy this code, this is just provided for explanation)

```
$query = 'SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE (
  (`firstname` LIKE ?)
  OR (`lastname` LIKE ?)
  OR (`adress` LIKE ?)
  OR (`email` LIKE ?)
  )
  AND (w_id=?) 
  LIMIT 0, 50';


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param("s", '%'.$search.'%');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $w_id);

    $search = $_GET['search'];;
    $w_id = $webshop_info['w_id'];

    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE ((`firstname` LIKE '%".$search."%')
  OR (`lastname` LIKE '%".$search."%')
  OR (`adress` LIKE '%".$search."%')
  OR (`email` LIKE '%".$search."%'))
  AND (w_id='{$webshop_info[w_id]}') LIMIT 0, 50
```

You have to have the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query ('w_id' between quotes):

```
"SELECT * FROM customers
   WHERE (`firstname` LIKE '%".$search."%' 
   OR `lastname` LIKE '%".$search."%'
   OR `adress` LIKE '%".$search."%'
   OR `email` LIKE '%".$search."%') AND w_id=". $webshop_info['w_id'] ." limit 0,50"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why '%".$search."%' 
Also, combine your OR's in ()

```
$raw_search_results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM customers
       WHERE (`firstname` LIKE '%$search%' 
       OR `lastname` LIKE '%$search%'
       OR `adress` LIKE '%$search%'
       OR `email` LIKE '%$search%') AND w_id='$webshop_info[w_id]' limit 0,50")
       or die(mysqli_error());
```